Getting (TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object ) while making choices in django
I'm new in django and I'm making this project for practice and gain practical experience.
There are 5 resources:

Users
Principal
Students
Teachers
Assignments

A principal can view all the teachers

A principal can view all the assignments submitted and/or graded by teachers.

A principal can re-grade the assignments already graded by the teacher.

A student can create and edit a draft assignment

A student can list all his created assignments

A student can submit a draft assignment to a teacher

A teacher can list all assignments submitted to him

A teacher can grade an assignment submitted to him


models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator

# Create your models here.

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            return ValueError("User must have an email Adress")

        if not username:
            return ValueError("User must have an username")

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email, 
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            password=password,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superadmin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    PRINCIPAL = 1
    TEACHER = 2
    STUDENT = 3

    ROLE_CHOICE = (
        (PRINCIPAL, 'Principal'),
        (TEACHER, 'Teacher'),
        (STUDENT, 'Student'),
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)


    # required field
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']


    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    



teacher = User.objects.filter(role=2)
teacher_choice = ((i.first_name.capitalize+i.last_name.capitalize,f'{i.first_name} {i.last_name}') for i in teacher)
print(teacher_choice)


class Assignment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    disc = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.CharField(choices=teacher_choice, max_length=200, null=True)


class Grade(models.Model):
    assignment = models.OneToOneField(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grade = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(10)])


error---->
Exception Value:cannot pickle 'generator' object
error ---> in Assignment class
teacher = models.CharField(choices=teacher_choice, max_length=200, null=True)

I'm trying to facilitate user to choose a particular teacher for the assignment submission. I have retrieved all the teacher from database and making a model with choice.
enter image description here

Change teacher_choices to a list comprehension.
teacher_choice = [(i.first_name.capitalize+i.last_name.capitalize,f'{i.first_name} {i.last_name}') for i in teacher]

